# Does elementary 0.4 loki supports 32-bit?

Tags: release-loki, hardware

I'm keen to instal this newest release from elementary OS. Unfortunately, I don't get an option to choose between 32 or 64 bit upon download. Does this mean that 32-bit support is dropped altogether? I cannot find the answer on the official pages from elementary.

Comment: That 64-bit worked fine on my 32 bit machine (Dell D630), except a small problem with touch pad that it's hard to move the cursor slowly.

Comment: @LU_XU _BU if you were able to install a 64bit OS on your computer then your computer is got HW that supports 64bit OS', vice versa is NOT true, you cannot install 64bit OS on HW that only supports 32bit OS
Your latitude D630 got a Core 2 Duo CPU which supports 64bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no 32-bit iso. Only 64bit.

Comment: Also, with Arch Linux dropping 32-bit, general support for 32-bit will be on the way out everywhere! http://www.pcworld.com/article/3164876/linux/arch-linux-pulls-the-plug-on-32-bit.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no official 32 bit elementary ISO but you can get quite close to the official experience by doing the following:

Install [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) 16.04.

Add the elementary PPAs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the elementary desktop:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Reboot and select the `Pantheon` session at the login screen.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's... not totally awful. The last time I experimented with this it caused all sorts of issues. Anything of note wrong with that installation? Kudos for going the extra mile.

Comment: The package doesn't exist

Comment: Extra tip: If you want to replace the unity login screen with the elementary one, remove the `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` config file.

Comment: Extra tip #2: Replace ubuntu boot splash with elementary's: `update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/elementar/elementary.plymouth 100`

Comment: Extra tip #3: Remove unity desktop `apt purge unity "unity-*"`

Answer (score -3):

I found an older 32 bit version @ http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Operating-Systems/Linux-Distributions/Elementary-OS-67717.shtml

Comment: you only have 0.3.2 freya in 32 bits